# Using Peter Weyl theorem to decompose an orbit

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $\pi$ be a unitary representation of $G$ on a Hilbert space $H$.
Since $G$ is finite, we have that for every $v \in H$, the orbit of $v$, $\pi (G).v$, is of dimension $\leq \vert G \vert$ and in particular it is finite.

Denote $V_v = span (\pi(G).v)$. If $dim (V_v)$ is of dimension $\vert G \vert$ (i.e., if the vectors $\lbrace \pi (g).v : g \in G \rbrace$ are linearly independent), then $V_v$ is isomorphic to $L^2 (G)$ with the left representation and therefore $\pi$ on $V_v$ decomposes according to the decomposition of $L^2 (G)$ in Peter Weyl theorem.

What can be said in case $dim (V_v) < \vert G \vert$? I want to say that each irreducible representation in the decomposition of the action of $\pi$ on $V_v$ appears with multiplicity less or equal to its degree  - is this true ?

If it is true - does it generalizes to orbits of compact groups of finite type (i.e., orbits whose span closure is of finite dimension)?

Comment: Yes, this is true; it follows from the observation that $V_v$ is, more or less by definition, a quotient of the regular representation.

Comment: Thanks - I knew it was something silly I was missing